# Azure AD Application Add User to Active Directory using Client Credentials

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add a user to an application Active Directory but with little success. I am using the GraphServiceClient with.Net Core

The documentation here says I need these permissions

[Azure AD Graph Client Beta Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-beta)

> Application   Directory.ReadWrite.All

But I cannot find where in the Azure Portal I can assign this permission.

[image]

The code is above, the GraphServiceClient is in beta at the moment and this is not part of the API yet, so I am calling the request manually.

Below is my code for authentication, I am using my applications client secret which is set against the application in the AD. I can read directory data fine.

```
public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            try
            {
                if (null == _configuration)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Azure AD Configuration is not set");
                }

                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
                    $"{_configuration.Instance}/{_configuration.Domain}", false);

                var credentials = new ClientCredential(_configuration.ClientId, _configuration.ClientSecret);

                var authResult =
                    await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credentials);

                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Authentication Provider, unable to get token", ex);
            }
        }
```

Update - After checking with Rohit's advice, you can see I have the permissions set. But notice they are all in blue with the ticks next to them! I have changed and saved, you can see the save button is disabled. I have clicked Grant Permissions. Is this relevant?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot find where in the Azure Portal I can assign this
>   permission.

In Azure portal navigate to Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > Your specific app > Settings > Required Permissions

[image]

Click on Add and Select Microsoft Graph

[image]

Now, in the Application Permissions section, check "Read and write directory data"

[image]

Once you're done, do "Grant Permissions" for Admin consent, as this permission needs it.

Comment: Odd I do actually have this set and I have done the 'Grant Permissions', still getting the same 401 error. Do I have to regenerate the Client Secret ?

Comment: Hmmm . No I just tried that, didn't work also, Don't know if it's relevant but a lot of the permissions are highlighted in blue, does this mean anything ?

Comment: I have added a picture to my original question.

Comment: It's ok, my bad. Got confused with environments. That sorted it!